# Difference between MPI_Allgather and MPI_Alltoall functions?

Tags: mpi

What is the main difference betweeen the MPI_Allgather and MPI_Alltoall functions in MPI?

I mean can some one give me examples where MPI_Allgather will be helpful and MPI_Alltoall will not? and vice versa.

I am not able to understand the main difference? It looks like in both the cases all the processes sends send_cnt elements to every other process participating in the communicator and receives them?

Thank You

Comment: TL;DR "All gather" is like gather+broadcast (or everyone does a gather). "All to all" is like transposing a matrix.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

A picture says more than thousand words, so here are several ASCII art pictures:

```
rank    send buf                        recv buf
----    --------                        --------
 0      a,b,c         MPI_Allgather     a,b,c,A,B,C,#,@,%
 1      A,B,C        ---------------->  a,b,c,A,B,C,#,@,%
 2      #,@,%                           a,b,c,A,B,C,#,@,%
```

This is just the regular `MPI_Gather`, only in this case all processes receive the data chunks, i.e. the operation is root-less.

```
rank    send buf                        recv buf
----    --------                        --------
 0      a,b,c          MPI_Alltoall     a,A,#
 1      A,B,C        ---------------->  b,B,@
 2      #,@,%                           c,C,%

(a more elaborate case with two elements per process)

rank    send buf                        recv buf
----    --------                        --------
 0      a,b,c,d,e,f    MPI_Alltoall     a,b,A,B,#,@
 1      A,B,C,D,E,F  ---------------->  c,d,C,D,%,$
 2      #,@,%,$,&,*                     e,f,E,F,&,*
```

(looks better if each element is coloured by the rank that sends it but...)

`MPI_Alltoall` works as combined `MPI_Scatter` and `MPI_Gather` - the send buffer in each process is split like in `MPI_Scatter` and then each column of chunks is gathered by the respective process, whose rank matches the number of the chunk column. `MPI_Alltoall` can also be seen as a global transposition operation, acting on chunks of data.

Is there a case when the two operations are interchangeable? To properly answer this question, one has to simply analyse the sizes of the data in the send buffer and of the data in the receive buffer:

```
operation      send buf size      recv buf size
---------      -------------      -------------
MPI_Allgather  sendcnt            n_procs * sendcnt
MPI_Alltoall   n_procs * sendcnt  n_procs * sendcnt
```

The receive buffer size is actually `n_procs * recvcnt`, but MPI mandates that the number of basic elements sent should be equal to the number of basic elements received, hence if the same MPI datatype is used in both send and receive parts of `MPI_All...`, then `recvcnt` must be equal to `sendcnt`.

It is immediately obvious that for the same size of the received data, the amount of data sent by each process is different. For the two operations to be equal, one necessary condition is that the sizes of the sent buffers in both cases are equal, i.e. `n_procs * sendcnt == sendcnt`, which is only possible if `n_procs == 1`, i.e. if there is only one process, or if `sendcnt == 0`, i.e. no data is being sent at all. Hence there is no practically viable case where both operations are really interchangeable. But one can simulate `MPI_Allgather` with `MPI_Alltoall` by repeating `n_procs` times the same data in the send buffer (as already noted by Tyler Gill). Here is the action of `MPI_Allgather` with one-element send buffers:

```
rank    send buf                        recv buf
----    --------                        --------
 0      a             MPI_Allgather     a,A,#
 1      A            ---------------->  a,A,#
 2      #                               a,A,#
```

And here the same implemented with `MPI_Alltoall`:

```
rank    send buf                        recv buf
----    --------                        --------
 0      a,a,a          MPI_Alltoall     a,A,#
 1      A,A,A        ---------------->  a,A,#
 2      #,#,#                           a,A,#
```

The reverse is not possible - one cannot simulate the action of `MPI_Alltoall` with `MPI_Allgather` in the general case.

Answer (score 24):

These two screenshots have a quick explanation:

*MPI_Allgatherv*

[image: MPI_Allgatherv]

*MPI_Alltoallv*

[image: MPI_Alltoallv]

Though this a comparison between MPI_Allgatherv and MPI_Alltoallv, but it also explains how MPI_Allgather differs from MPI_Alltoall.

Answer (score 4):

While these two methods are indeed very similar, there seems to be one crucial difference between the two of them.

MPI_Allgather ends with each process having the exact same data in its receive buffer, and each process contributes a single value to the overall array. For example, if each of a set of processes needed to share some single value about their state with everyone else, each would provide their single value. These values would then be sent to everyone, so everyone would have a copy of the same structure.

MPI_Alltoall does not send the same values to each other process. Instead of providing a single value that should be shared with each other process, each process specifies one value to give to each other process. In other words, with n processes, each must specify n values to share. Then, for each processor j, its k'th value will be sent to process k's j'th index in the receive buffer. This is useful if each process has a single, unique message for each other process.

As a final note, the results of running allgather and alltoall would be the same in the case where each process filled its send buffer with the same value. The only difference would be that allgather would likely be much more efficient.