# Can more than 1 process use MPI_Scatter?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing

Assume I have 3 processes that have the following arrays:

```
P0 - int sendBuff[3] = {1,2,3};
P1 - int sendBuff[3] = {4,5,6};
P2 - int sendBuff[3] = {7,8,9};
```

Assume each process has a `int recvBuff[3];`

I want to scatter each process sendBuff into each process recvBuff, so I have the code in my main file:

```
int rank, size, i;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

MPI_Scatter(&sendBuff[0], 1, MPI_INT, &recvBuff[0], 3, MPI_INT, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
//print recvBuffs
```

However, when I print out the processes `recvBuff`, I get:

```
recvBuff of P0:  1, -1077259864, 134517329
recvBuff of P1:  5, 6, 4
recvBuff of P2:  9, 7, 8
```

Should I not get:

```
recvBuff of P0:  1, 4, 7
recvBuff of P1:  2, 5, 8
recvBuff of P2:  3, 6, 9
```

I have a feeling each process is overwriting the recvBuff of each process everytime they call `MPI_Scatter`.

Also, can only one process in a group of processes call MPI_Scatter or can all of them call it in parallel?

Thank you.

Comment: apparently, what i was looking for was MPI_Alltoall(..), but it seems that I still cant get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, what I was looking for was MPI_Alltoall(..)

Apparently, what I was trying to do is easily done with MPI_Alltoall(..)

Anyone who has the same question can look at : [Hiestro Liev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049190/difference-between-mpi-allgather-and-mpi-alltoall-functions)

For completeness sake:

Scatter is for one process to send values to all the other processes:

```
P0- {1, 2, 3}
P1
P2
```

After scatter:

```
P0-{1}
P1-{2}
P2-{3}
```

Also, the "root" parameter in the Scatter operation should be the same for all the processes because it means scatter the array at the root location to all the other processes. In the example above, that value is 0.

(Compliments of VAARNAN DROLIA from NUS)